# CSS border property didn't work when I used it without border-style property

Tags: html, css, border

I tried to add  border  property for a text part wrapping by div tag. But it didn't work. what's the reason? after using border property and border-style:solid;,it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Border style in div</title>
    <style>
      div {
        border: solid;
        background: aqua;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- div start -->
    <div>
      <!-- paragraph  start-->
      <p> guys  am sagar shahu</p>
      <!-- paragraph end -->
    </div>
    <!-- div end -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sagar, I'm grateful to your reply. According to your code I obtained black border with aqua color background but my seeking ,way is only aqua color border without background color.

Comment: It's my pleasure to help u brother.you can ask me anythingrelated to front end .

Comment: Thank you! Sagar